# Angular 2 get data from ID using web api

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have web API method to get data from EmpID and I call this method from Angular 2 and want to bind data to form to update that.

I think I do not call web API method correctly from service,
but it gives error that we cannot find this web API method.

Web API method:

```
    [ Route("api/Employee/GetEdit/{id:int}") ]       
    public Employee GetEdit(int id) {
        return db.Employees.Where(t => t.EmpID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Below is my service:

```
 GetEdit(id:any) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:49221/Employee/GetEdit/' + id,  headers)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());

    //return this.http.get('http://localhost:49221/api/Employee')
    //    .map(this.extractData)
    //    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Below is my component class:

```
 getEdit() {
    this._service.GetEdit(1).subscribe(              
        posts => this.employee = posts,
        error => console.error(error)
    )};
```

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser if you are getting a cross origin request error

Comment: @Malwaregeek , yes I got cross origin network error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks just fine, but I think you have forgotten to put *api* in your url and that's why you are not getting the information you need.

You can also consider creating a variable for a base url and then just adding the id to the end of it, that way your code will become cleaner.

```
GetEdit(id:any) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:49221/api/Employee/GetEdit/' + id,  headers)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());

    //return this.http.get('http://localhost:49221/api/Employee')
    //    .map(this.extractData)
    //    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

This is the fixed version of your http call with the *api* keyword added to the url.

P.S: You can also consider casting the response to the exact object(if you have a specific class created for the purpose)

Something like this:

```
getEdit() {
    this._service.GetEdit(1).subscribe(              
        posts => this.employee = <Employee>posts,
        error => console.error(error)
    )};
```

As I said this is considering the fact that you've created an Employee class.